# I need a explanation for code of "beginning android games"

Tags: java, android

I am reading the book "Beginning Android Games" since last couple of days. But I am stuck to understand the code.

You can check or download the code here:
http://code.google.com/p/beginnginandroidgames2/downloads/list

The project I mean is `ch06-mr-mom`. The Activity is called `MrNomGame`:

```
public abstract class AndroidGame extends Activity implements Game {

    AndroidFastRenderView renderView;
    Graphics graphics;
    Audio audio;
    Input input;
    FileIO fileIO;
    Screen screen;
    WakeLock wakeLock;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        boolean isLandscape = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        int frameBufferWidth = isLandscape ? 480 : 320;
        int frameBufferHeight = isLandscape ? 320 : 480;
        Bitmap frameBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameBufferWidth,
                frameBufferHeight, Config.RGB_565);

        float scaleX = (float) frameBufferWidth
                / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        float scaleY = (float) frameBufferHeight
                / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        renderView = new AndroidFastRenderView(this, frameBuffer);
        graphics = new AndroidGraphics(getAssets(), frameBuffer);
        fileIO = new AndroidFileIO(this);
        audio = new AndroidAudio(this);
        input = new AndroidInput(this, renderView, scaleX, scaleY);
        screen = getStartScreen();
        setContentView(renderView);

        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "GLGame");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        wakeLock.acquire();
        screen.resume();
        renderView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        wakeLock.release();
        renderView.pause();
        screen.pause();

        if (isFinishing())
            screen.dispose();
    }

    public Input getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public FileIO getFileIO() {
        return fileIO;
    }

    public Graphics getGraphics() {
        return graphics;
    }

    public Audio getAudio() {
        return audio;
    }

    public void setScreen(Screen screen) {
        if (screen == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Screen must not be null");

        this.screen.pause();
        this.screen.dispose();
        screen.resume();
        screen.update(0);
        this.screen = screen;
    }

    public Screen getCurrentScreen() {
        return screen;
    }
}
```

The class implements the interface `Game` :

```
package com.badlogic.androidgames.framework;

public interface Game {
    public Input getInput();
    public FileIO getFileIO();
    public Graphics getGraphics();
    public Audio getAudio();
    public void setScreen(Screen screen);
    public Screen getCurrentScreen();
    public Screen getStartScreen();
}
```

**My first question is:** I missed the implementation of the method `getStartScreen()` of the interface `Game`. Usually I have to implement all methods of an interface.

Anyway, now the `onCreate` is running. At this line:

```
screen = getStartScreen();
```

The program goes back to the origin class `MrNomGame`, where the method `getStartScreen()` gives an object of `LoadingScreen` to the variable `screen`. Class `LoadingScreen`:

```
public class LoadingScreen extends Screen {

    public LoadingScreen(Game game) {
        super(game);
    }

    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
        Assets.background = g.newPixmap("background.png", PixmapFormat.RGB565);
        Assets.logo = g.newPixmap("logo.png", PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
        Assets.mainMenu = g.newPixmap("mainmenu.png", PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
        Assets.buttons = g.newPixmap("buttons.png", PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
        Assets.help1 = g.newPixmap("help1.png", PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
        Assets.help2 = g.newPixmap("help2.png", PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
        Assets.help3 = g.newPixmap("help3.png", PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
        Assets.numbers = g.newPixmap("numbers.png", PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
        Assets.ready = g.newPixmap("ready.png", PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
        Assets.pause = g.newPixmap("pausemenu.png", PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
        Assets.gameOver = g.newPixmap("gameover.png", PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
        Assets.headUp = g.newPixmap("headup.png", PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
        Assets.headLeft = g.newPixmap("headleft.png", PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
        Assets.headDown = g.newPixmap("headdown.png", PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
        Assets.headRight = g.newPixmap("headright.png", PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
        Assets.tail = g.newPixmap("tail.png", PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
        Assets.stain1 = g.newPixmap("stain1.png", PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
        Assets.stain2 = g.newPixmap("stain2.png", PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
        Assets.stain3 = g.newPixmap("stain3.png", PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
        Assets.click = game.getAudio().newSound("click.ogg");
        Assets.eat = game.getAudio().newSound("eat.ogg");
        Assets.bitten = game.getAudio().newSound("bitten.ogg");
        Settings.load(game.getFileIO());
        game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));
    }

    public void present(float deltaTime) {

    }

    public void pause() {

    }

    public void resume() {

    }

    public void dispose() {

    }
}
```

Class `Screen`:

```
public abstract class Screen {
    protected final Game game;

    public Screen(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public abstract void update(float deltaTime);
    public abstract void present(float deltaTime);
    public abstract void pause();
    public abstract void resume();
    public abstract void dispose();
}
```

After a certain time, the `onCreate()` method is finished. But in the Debug-Mode the screen of my mobile phone is already black and dark. It seems to be the program is in a loop. I can press F6 as often as I want. But when I resume the Main-Menu will shown. If you look in the code you will see that the Main-Menu will call in the `update()` method of `loadingScreen`.

**My big question is:** What happens after the `onCreate()` method is finished and how the program get into the `update()` method of `loadingScreen`?

I know that is a lot of code. But it would be very useful for me to understand it.

Comment: God bless brave Stackoverflowers who read till the end.

Comment: there is something wrong with your update method. it calls Game.setScreen, and your Game implementation calls update at the end of setScreen. It looks like an infinite recursion to me.

Comment: @njzk2 at first, `screen` is an instance of `LoadingScreen`. The `update` of that class sets `screen` to an instance of `MainMenuScreen`. Hence, the new `update` is called on a different class.

Comment: @Heuster : true, but it seems strange that 2 childs of Screen would have such a radically different behaviour.

Comment: @njzk2 absolutely. I would say the code is quite verbose for tutorial code anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first question: `AndroidGame` is an *abstract* class. This means it doesn't have to implement all methods of `Game`, as long as one of the classes extending `AndroidGame` does this. As you can see from the code, this is done in `MrNomGame`:

```
public class MrNomGame extends AndroidGame {
    public Screen getStartScreen() {
        return new LoadingScreen(this); 
    }
}
```

Now for your big question:

In `onCreate`, a renderer is created:

```
renderView = new AndroidFastRenderView(this, frameBuffer);
```

If you have a look at that class, you see that `onResume` creates a new thread that runs the following code:

```
public void run() {
    Rect dstRect = new Rect();
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    while(running) {  
        if(!holder.getSurface().isValid())
            continue;           

        float deltaTime = (System.nanoTime()-startTime) / 1000000000.0f;
        startTime = System.nanoTime();

        game.getCurrentScreen().update(deltaTime);
        game.getCurrentScreen().present(deltaTime);

        Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.getClipBounds(dstRect);
        canvas.drawBitmap(framebuffer, null, dstRect, null);
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}
```

So, it repetitively calls `update` on the current screen, which is the instance of `LoadingScreen`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Another question: What calls the methods "onResume" and "run" in "AndroidFastRenderView"? And why I need this interface "runnable"? Maybe I don't understand the purpose of an interface. I think it deals with the "SurfaceView" Class which is extended by "AndroidFastRenderView".

Comment: @PeterPanne As you can see in the code you posted, `AndroidGame.onResume` calls the `resume` method in `AndroidFastRenderView` (if you want to know why that `onResume` is called, have a look at the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)). The `run` method is called by `renderThread.start()`. This is because `AndroidFastRenderView` implements `Runnable`, which means it can be run in a separate thread, in order not to freeze the GUI.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think now I understand it. The while-Loop in "run" is an endless loop. So it needs its own thread, otherwise the will app get freezed. I don't know enough about the interface "runnable", but I know that it is needed, because the class is just able to extends one class. Therefore you need the interface. At the moment I don't understand the whole topic of interfaces. I will open a new thread soon to ask some things about it. Thank you very much again for anwsering my questions.