# when is "update" method in a class run in Java?

Tags: java, class, syntax

A basic Java question i guess. I am going through a tutorial in which I have a custom class "LoadingScreen" (extends another custom class "Screen").

As soon as "LoadingScreen" class is called, the "update()" method runs.

Question is WHERE is the update() method being called from? Is that something default in Java that update() method is called with the constructor?

```
public class LoadingScreen extends Screen {

public LoadingScreen(Game game) { //constructor for this class
    super(game);
}

@Override
public void update(float deltaTime) {
    Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
    Assets.background = g.newPixmap("background.png", Graphics.PixmapFormat.RGB565);
    Assets.logo = g.newPixmap("logo.png", Graphics.PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
    Assets.mainMenu = g.newPixmap("mainmenu.png", Graphics.PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
    Assets.buttons = g.newPixmap("buttons.png", Graphics.PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
    Assets.help1 = g.newPixmap("help1.png", Graphics.PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
    Assets.help2 = g.newPixmap("help2.png", Graphics.PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
    Assets.help3 = g.newPixmap("help3.png", Graphics.PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
    Assets.numbers = g.newPixmap("numbers.png", Graphics.PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
    Assets.ready = g.newPixmap("ready.png", Graphics.PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
    Assets.pause = g.newPixmap("pausemenu.png", Graphics.PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
    Assets.gameOver = g.newPixmap("gameover.png", Graphics.PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
    Assets.headUp = g.newPixmap("headup.png", Graphics.PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
    Assets.headLeft = g.newPixmap("headleft.png", Graphics.PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
    Assets.headDown = g.newPixmap("headdown.png", Graphics.PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
    Assets.headRight = g.newPixmap("headright.png", Graphics.PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
    Assets.tail = g.newPixmap("tail.png", Graphics.PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
    Assets.stain1 = g.newPixmap("stain1.png", Graphics.PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
    Assets.stain2 = g.newPixmap("stain2.png", Graphics.PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);
    Assets.stain3 = g.newPixmap("stain3.png", Graphics.PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);

    Assets.click = game.getAudio().newSound("click.ogg");
    Assets.eat = game.getAudio().newSound("eat.ogg");
    Assets.bitten = game.getAudio().newSound("bitten.ogg");

    Settings.load(game.getFileIO());
    game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));
}

@Override
public void present(float deltaTime) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
}
```

UPDATE 1: Adding "Screen" class

```
public abstract class Screen {
protected final Game game;

public Screen(Game game) {
    this.game = game;
}

public abstract void update(float deltaTime);

public abstract void present(float deltaTime);

public abstract void pause();

public abstract void resume();

public abstract void dispose();
}
```

UPDATE 2: Adding 'Game' Interface

package com.neil.gamesbook.framework;

```
public interface Game {
public Input getInput();

public FileIO getFileIO();

public Graphics getGraphics();

public Audio getAudio();

public void setScreen(Screen screen);

public Screen getCurrentScreen();

public Screen getStartScreen();
}
```

Comment: What does `Screen` extend?

Comment: updated the question with Screen class. It does not extend anything, it is just an abstract class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is that something default in Java that update() method is called with
>   the constructor?

No, constructors doesn't call anything by default.

> Question is WHERE is the update() method being called from?

Your constructor here calls super class's constructor. So probably `update()` is called from there. You should look into the constructor of `Screen` class.

**EDIT**
That sentence in the book is not correct. It seems AndroidGame constructor indirectly calls update(). See this: [I need a explanation for code of "beginning android games"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916697/i-need-a-explanation-for-code-of-beginning-android-games)

Comment: I updated the question with the Screen class, but I still dont get where the "update()" method is getting called from.

Comment: That sentence in the book is not correct. It seems `AndroidGame` constructor indirectly calls `update()`. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916697/i-need-a-explanation-for-code-of-beginning-android-games

Comment: You are right. Thanks for this answer, good one. Marking your response as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, the constructor does not call any methods by default.

What do you mean when you say 'As soon as "LoadingScreen" class is called, the "update()" method runs.'? Do you mean creating instances of the LoadingScreen class?

Comment: Yes, I mean when an instance of the LoadingScreen is created, the "update()" method is called. Is that expected? Are all the functions [pause(), resume(), ...]) being called?

Comment: Then as @Caner suggested below, you should look at the `Screen` class constructor. The `Screen` class might also be extend'ing some other classes, so the `Update()` method could be called from any of the constructors in the class hierarchy.

Comment: I updated the question with the Screen class, but I still dont get where the "update()" method (in class LoadingScreen) is getting called from.

Comment: Just looked at your edits. I doubt that the `Update()` method is being called when you instantiate the `LoadingScreen` class - new LoadingScreen(). I guess it is being called from externally. Are you passing the instantiated object to any function? 
Do you call setScreen(screen) method with you instance?